# Why is this cryptosystem insecure?

Tags: provable-security

Can someone help me see the flaw in this cryptosystem?

Note: This is homework and it is due today at 1:30pm. An answer before that is not expected; I'd just like to understand what the flaw is.

From *An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography* By Jeffrey Hoffstein, Jill Pipher and Joseph H. Silverman (Springer, 2008); problem 3.10, found one click away from [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=isbn%3A0387779949+page+178):

> Alice chooses two large primes $p$ and $q$ and she publishes $N = pq$. It is assumed
>   that $N$ is hard to factor. Alice also chooses three random numbers $g$, $r_1$, and $r_2$ modulo $N$ and computes
>   $$g_1\equiv g^{r_1\cdot(p−1)}\pmod N\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }g_2\equiv g^{r_2\cdot(q−1)}\pmod N.$$
>
> Her public key is the triple $(N,g_1,g_2)$ and her private key is the pair of primes $(p,q)$.
>
> Now Bob wants to send the message $m$ to Alice, where $m$ is a number modulo $N$. He chooses two random integers $s_1$ and $s_2$ modulo $N$ and computes
>   $$c_1\equiv m\cdot{g_1}^{s_1}\pmod N\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }c_2\equiv m\cdot{g_2}^{s_2}\pmod N.$$
>   Bob sends the ciphertext $(c_1,c_2)$ to Alice.
>
> Decryption is extremely fast and easy. Alice use the Chinese remainder theorem
>   to solve the pair of congruences
>   $$x\equiv c_1\pmod p\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }x\equiv c_2\pmod q.$$
>
> (a) Prove that Alice’s solution $x$ is equal to Bob’s plaintext $m$.
>   (b) Explain why this cryptosystem is not secure.

I can verify A but am having trouble seeing where the cryptosystem is weak.
Avenues I've explored:

1. The modulus is factorable
2. The encrypted text is easily decryptable

But I'm just not seeing the answer. Can I have some help?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the question what the math is. You can use TeX style formatting to clarify. Also, it is probably not wise to link to material that likely violates copyright law.

Comment: Hint: what is $g_1 \bmod p$?  How can the attacker use that to factor $N$?

Comment: g1 mod p and g2 mod q are both 1. Which would mean that (g1-1)*(g2-1) mod n = 0 which I would think implies that g1-1 and g2-2 are the factors of n but that's not the case.

Comment: Oh! But they are factors of some multiple of n!

Comment: @poncho So because I can discover p and q simply from the public keys by an exhaustive search, the cryptosystem is insecure? Or is there a more clever way to find them than an exhaustive search?

Comment: Hint: use GCD...

Comment: Ah ha! You guys are wonderful, thank you. My professor has jumped right into advanced attacks and gave us very little teaching on this basic stuff. Thank you again!

Comment: Kairos, now that you got it, might I suggest you answer the question below?  That way, other people looking at the question later will see the answer, not just the hints (and it will firm up in your mind exactly what the answer is)

Comment: I actually had a post typed out but then I figured that it might be better for them to analyze the comments and obtain that learning rather than providing the full fledged answer. I'll defer to the experts in this regard though.

Answer (score 5):

From the key creators point of view, notice that:$g_1\bmod p=1$ and $g_2\bmod q=1$.

Which means that $(g_1-1)\cdot(g_2-1)\bmod N=0$.

Which implies that $g_1-1$ and $g_2-1$ share a common divisor with $p$ and $q$.

To obtain $p$ we simply take $\gcd(g_1-1,N)$.

To obtain $q$ we simply take $\gcd(g_2-1,N)$, or $N/p$.

Because we have been able to factor the modulus using only the public keys and with no protocol error on the part of the implementer, this cryptosystem is insecure.